# Is there a way to specify the column name generated by the inline_outer function in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table named `order` like this:

| id | campaigns |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | [{"id": "1", "title": "test", "type": "one"}, {"id": "2", "title": "test2", "type": "two"}] |
| 5 | [{"id": "3", "title": "test3", "type": "three"}] |

What I expect:

| id | campaignId | title | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | test | one |
| 2 | 2 | test2 | two |
| 5 | 3 | test3 | three |

My code:

```sql
SELECT orderId AS id, id AS campaignid, title, type
FROM (
    SELECT id AS orderId, inline_outer(from_json(campaigns, 'ARRAY<STRUCT<id: STRING, title: STRING, type: STRING>>'))
    FROM order
);
```

I have to rename the `id` field to `orderId` in subQuery because my `campaigns` field include an `id` key.

**Question: Is there a way to specify the column name generated by the inline_outer function in Spark SQL?**

What I tried:

```sql
SELECT id, inline_outer(from_json(campaigns, 'ARRAY<STRUCT<id: STRING, title: STRING, type: STRING>>')) AS ('campaignId', 'title', 'type')
FROM order;
```

```sql
SELECT id, inline_outer(from_json(campaigns, 'ARRAY<STRUCT<id: STRING, title: STRING, type: STRING>>')) AS {'campaignId', 'title', 'type'}
FROM order;
```

However, the above two methods do not conform to the syntax of Spark SQL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure you want to use spark sql ? it would be easier using spark functions.

Comment: `campaigns` is a string or an array of struct ?

Comment: @Steven Yes, I want to use Spark SQL or PySpark. `campaigns` is a JSON string, so I used  from_json function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `cast` the `from_json` output and change the column name:

```sql
SELECT 
    id, 
    inline_outer(cast(from_json(campaigns, 'ARRAY<STRUCT<id: STRING, title: STRING, type: STRING>>') AS ARRAY<STRUCT<campaignId: STRING, title: STRING, type: STRING>>)) 
FROM order;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using full pyspark :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

# Define schema of the JSON
schema = T.ArrayType(
    T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("id", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("title", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("type", T.StringType()),
        ]
    )
)
# OR you can use also this schema with your current example
schema = T.ArrayType(T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()))

# Convert string to struct 
df = df.withColumn(
    "campaigns",
    F.from_json("campaigns", schema),
)

# Explode the array
df = df.withColumn("campaign", F.explode("campaigns"))

# Rename the field
df = df.select(
    "id",
    F.col("campaign.id").alias("caimpagnId"),
    F.col("campaign.title"),
    F.col("campaign.type"),
)
```

```
+---+----------+-----+-----+
| id|caimpagnId|title| type|
+---+----------+-----+-----+
|  2|         1| test|  one|
|  2|         2|test2|  two|
|  5|         3|test3|three|
+---+----------+-----+-----+
```